# Using Conditional Formatting to highlight a cell based on an adjacent cell, but only if the cell being formatted is blank

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a conditional format that will highlight a cell if it is empty and an adjacent cell has the word "Closed" in it. I basically want to use the highlight as an alert for the user that if the cell contains "Closed" they need to put the closed date into the highlighted cell. In the picture below, the "Status" column is what I want to base my format on and the right most column is the cell I want to highlight, until the date is put in.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dates/blanks in `A2:A100` and Status (e.g. Closed etc.) in `B2:B100` then just select the `A2:A100` range and use this formula in conditional formatting

`=AND(A2="",B2="Closed")`

That will work for the whole range

Answer (score 1):

Select cell B1.

Go to `Home`, `Conditional Formatting`, `Highlight cell rules`, `More rules`.

Choose rule type `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

Formula:

```
=AND(A1="Closed";B1="")
```

In my example I put the word *Closed* in cell A1 and highlight B1.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem largely correct, except it should be, as far as I understand:

Select column **D**. Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight cell rules > More rules, then select use a formula etc.

Formula:

```
=AND(A1="Closed",D1="")
```

And don't forget to set the formatting.